# Echo misses ^ characters when long string

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the following command in a windows batch script

```
echo =%%k-16,INDIRECT.EXT^("'C:\Users\...\Analysis\[ObsStreamflow.xlsx]Sheet1'^!A%%k"^),INDIRECT.EXT^("'C:\Users\...\Analysis\[sim%%j.xlsx]Sheet1'^!B!val!"^),^=C%%k/1000,^=D%%k-B%%k,^=ABS^(E%%k^),^=(E%%k^)^^2,=^(B%%k-B10^),=Sqrt^(B%%k^),=SQRT^(D%%k^),=^(J%%k - B13^)^^2   >>t%%j.csv
```

where the omitted file path is 38 characters long (I don't think I'm hitting the line limits, but just in case this is the problem).  This is a single line in my .bat file, shown here as multiple lines just to make things more readable.

The output is mostly correct, except that where I have ^^2, it just becomes 2 (so I have =(E1)2 and =(J1-B13)2.  If I omit the Indirect.Ext text, and just have

```
echo =%%k-16,a1,b1,^=C%%k/1000,^=D%%k-B%%k,^=ABS^(E%%k^),^=(E%%k^)^^2,=^(B%%k-B10^),=Sqrt^(B%%k^),=SQRT^(D%%k^),=^(J%%k - B13^)^^2   >>t%%j.csv
```

it prints correctly, so the relevant comments show as =(E1)^2 and =(J1-B13)^2, which is what I am after.

I've not had any luck finding an answer, everything I have found just points to using ^^ to get echo to return ^.  I cannot break this command into multiple lines, I need it to be a single row in csv format.

Any suggestions for a fix much appreciated, I only really need to use this for a week or so, don't need an elegant solution, just one that works. - I'm very new to bat scripts (and indeed programming in general), will keep trying different ideas in the mean time.

Comment: It's easier to solve problems if you show all of the relevant data, input, output and desired output. As it stands, it appears you are using `%%j` and `%%k` so presumably this is in a loop, and from the partial results you've given it appears `%%k`=1 Here's my result from running your code with `%%k`=1 and `%%j`=jjj: `=1-16,INDIRECT.EXT("'C:\Users\...\Analysis\[ObsStreamflow.xlsx]Sheet1'^!A1"),INDIRECT.EXT("'C:\Users\...\Analysis\[simjjj.xlsx]Sheet1'^!B!val!"),=C1/1000,=D1-B1,=ABS(E1),=(E1)^2,=(B1-B10),=Sqrt(B1),=SQRT(D1),=(J1 - B13)^2` which appears to contain the ^2 you claim is missing.

Comment: Now it may be that the part-expression `!B!val!` is the source of the problem if you have `delayedexpansion` invoked - but we don't know because we're not beig given the entire input-line, output-line, desired-output-line, processing method and environment conditions.

Comment: Hi Peter - thanks for your response.  I'm sorry I didn't post a sufficient amount of the code to be useful, as I mentioned I'm very new to programming and I thought I had posted enough for it to make sense without being full of useless stuff - sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only the exclamation mark that creates the problems for you.

If at least one `!` is in your line (and delayed expansion is enabled), then a second caret escape phase will be started.
In this phase quotes aren't regarded, only carets.

A small test

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo one^1
echo two^^2
echo two^^2 With exclam!
echo five^^^^^& With exclam!
```

Output

```
one1
two^2
two2 With exclam
four^& With exclam
```

So in your sample, you need five carets.
Four to create one caret and the last one to escape the `)`, as the escape of the special character is only once required.

Comment: Thanks jeb - this has solved my problem, much appreciated, I couldn't for the life of me figure out what was in those commands that caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your specific problem is but you can use a trick in Windows to emulate `echo -n` (echo without a newline).

The commands:

```
<nul:  >file.csv set /p junk=first field
<nul: >>file.csv set /p junk=,second field
      >>file.csv echo ,third field
```

will result in a *single* line:

```
first field,second field,third field
```

That may make it easier for you to avoid the specific problem and, as a bonus, clean up your script so it's a little more readable (such as one field per script line).

It works because `set /p var=prompt` is the input command. It first outputs `prompt` without a newline then waits for the user to enter something, assigning it to the `var` environment variable.

By getting input from `nul:`, you basically give it an empty string so it doesn't wait. The prompt is output to `file.csv` without the newline.

In any case, for something *this* complex, I'd be bypassing `cmd.exe` for something a little more powerful such as the UNIX text processing tools under CygWin or MinGW (which require installation but are well worth it), or even VBScript scripts (which should be on Windows by default), where you can more easily control the output.

Comment: +1: But in this case it fails, as the text begins with an equal sign and equal and whitespaces don't work with set/p at the first characters